# Issue : Serializing using Jersey, Deserializing JSON using gson

Tags: web-services, json, rest, jersey, gson

I have been using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) for REST API and returning JSON. On client side I am using [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). While deserializing JSON, I am getting following error.

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer MapTypeAdapter failed to deserialized json object {} given the type interface java.util.Map
        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:63)
        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:88)
        at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:116)
        at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.navigateClassFields(ObjectNavigator.java:158)
        at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationCo
```

The Object which is being serialized to JSON by Jersey is having non-generic(no type specified) Map and List

```
public class Dealer implements Serializable
{
  private String serviceURL;
  private Map hoursService;
  List dealerAttributes;  
}
```

Here is the JSON generated by Jersey

```
{"serviceURL":www.google.com,"hoursService":{"3":{"dayOfWeek":3,"closeTime":"6:30 PM","openTime":"7:30 AM"},"2":{"dayOfWeek":2,"closeTime":"6:30 PM","openTime":"7:30 AM"},"1":{"dayOfWeek":1,"closeTime":"6:30 PM","openTime":"7:30 AM"}},"dealerAttributes":[{"language":"English","dealerAttributeName":"Spanish Speaking","updateDate":1174971061000},{"language":"English","updateDate":1103003316000}]}
```

What could be the reason. Please help me to resolve this issue. Is there any other utility which is better than gson? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424263/json-decode-custom-class-with-hashmap-member-using-gson-in-java

Answer (score 2):

The example JSON is invalid. http://jsonlint.com

www.google.com must be enclosed with quotes.  Then it is valid.

With the JSON corrected, the following deserialization example outputs

```
[Dealer: serviceURL=www.google.com, hoursService={
1=[Hours: dayOfWeek=1, closeTime=6:30 PM, openTime=7:30 AM], 
2=[Hours: dayOfWeek=2, closeTime=6:30 PM, openTime=7:30 AM], 
3=[Hours: dayOfWeek=3, closeTime=6:30 PM, openTime=7:30 AM]}, 
dealerAttributes=[
[DealerAttributes: language=English, dealerAttributeName=Spanish Speaking, updateDate=1174971061000], 
[DealerAttributes: language=English, dealerAttributeName=null, updateDate=1103003316000]]]
```

```
public class Foo
{
  static String jsonInput = 
    "{" + 
      "\"serviceURL\":\"www.google.com\"," + 
      "\"hoursService\":" +
      "{" + 
        "\"1\":" +
        "{" + 
          "\"dayOfWeek\":1," + 
          "\"closeTime\":\"6:30 PM\"," + 
          "\"openTime\":\"7:30 AM\"" + 
        "}," + 
        "\"2\":" +
        "{" + 
          "\"dayOfWeek\":2," + 
          "\"closeTime\":\"6:30 PM\"," + 
          "\"openTime\":\"7:30 AM\"" + 
        "}," + 
        "\"3\":" +
        "{" + 
          "\"dayOfWeek\":3," + 
          "\"closeTime\":\"6:30 PM\"," + 
          "\"openTime\":\"7:30 AM\"" + 
        "}" + 
      "}," + 
      "\"dealerAttributes\":" +
      "[" + 
        "{" + 
          "\"language\":\"English\"," + 
          "\"dealerAttributeName\":\"Spanish Speaking\"," + 
          "\"updateDate\":1174971061000" + 
        "}," + 
        "{" + 
          "\"language\":\"English\"," + 
          "\"updateDate\":1103003316000" + 
        "}" + 
      "]" + 
    "}";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    Dealer dealer = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, Dealer.class);
    System.out.println(dealer);
  }
}

class Dealer
{
  private String serviceURL;
  private Map<String, Hours> hoursService;
  private List<DealerAttributes> dealerAttributes;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format(
      "[Dealer: serviceURL=%1$s, hoursService=%2$s, dealerAttributes=%3$s]",
      serviceURL, hoursService, dealerAttributes);
  }
}

class Hours
{
  private int dayOfWeek;
  private String closeTime;
  private String openTime;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format(
      "[Hours: dayOfWeek=%1$d, closeTime=%2$s, openTime=%3$s]",
      dayOfWeek, closeTime, openTime);
  }
}

class DealerAttributes
{
  private String language;
  private String dealerAttributeName;
  private long updateDate;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format(
      "[DealerAttributes: language=%1$s, dealerAttributeName=%2$s, updateDate=%3$d]",
      language, dealerAttributeName, updateDate);
  }
}
```

This does use generic types, which I understand you said you weren't using to serialize, but are you stuck with the same limitation when deserialization?  If so, then you'll have to implement some more "manual" deserialization parsing, because, as the docs say, ["[w]hile deserializing, Collection must be of a specific generic type"](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples).